# call a method in a java class with jsf

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, snmp

this is the bean

```
       package Bean;
      public class AlarmeBean {

public String getOID() {
    return OID;
}
public void setOID(String oID) {
    OID = oID;
}
public String getAdrip() {
    return adrip;
}
public void setAdrip(String adrip) {
    this.adrip = adrip;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getSeverity() {
    return severity;
}
public void setSeverity(String severity) {
    this.severity = severity;
}
private String OID;
private String adrip;
private String date;
private String severity;


public void alarme(){
    Manager manager=new Manager(162);   
System.out.println("listnning on :"+manager.trapReceiver.getPort());


manager.trapReceiver.addTrapListener(manager);

   }
```

this is the class manager

```
          package Bean;

          import com.adventnet.snmp.beans.SnmpTrapReceiver;
         import com.adventnet.snmp.beans.TrapEvent;
          import com.adventnet.snmp.beans.TrapListener;

    public class Manager implements TrapListener {
SnmpTrapReceiver trapReceiver =new SnmpTrapReceiver();



         public Manager(int port ){

       trapReceiver.setPort(port);

            }


public void receivedTrap(TrapEvent trapEvent) {
    System.out.println("TrapEvent received." + "\n" +
         "Received a trap from:" + trapEvent.getRemoteHost () + 
           "Community is:" + trapEvent.getCommunity () + "\n" +
     "Agent Address is:" + trapEvent.getAgentAddress () + "\n" +
         "Enterprise OID:" + trapEvent.getEnterprise () + "\n" +
       "Trap Variable OID:" + trapEvent.getObjectID (0) + 
                            "\n");
              }

         }
```

and in the xhtml i writed a commandbutoom to call the alarme methode in the alarmeBean

```
   <p:commandButton process="form" value="call" action={AlarmeBean.alarme}" />
```

but i have this error : *La classe de bean ou de propriété «Bean.Alarme» du bean géré «alarmeBean» ne peut pas être chargée à cause de l’absence de la dépendance com/adventnet/snmp/beans/TrapListener.*

if i execute the class manager out of this web project it works normally but (it will rturn in the console "listnning on :162")

Comment: Change the 
public void alarme(){ to 
public String alarme(){ and return the null value like "return null;"

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access a class method directly. you should add @javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean annotation to class or define in faces-config.xml. @ManagedBean is more useful. 
please try that:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "alermeBean")
@RequestScoped
public class AlarmeBean {

    public void alerme() {

    }

}
```

xhtml:

```xhtml
<p:commandButton process="@form" value="call" action="#{alarmeBean.alarme}" />
```

Comment: You rendered the first letter of the managed-bean's name here lowercase: `action=#{alarmeBean.alarme}"` ?

Comment: @Ormar common usage for ManagedBean names is lowercase for first letter. But this is not a must. you can change managed bean name in annotitation @ManagedBean(name = "alermeBean")

Comment: i just add adventnet jar in the folder /WEB-INF/build  so i havn't any error ,  but also i havn't any action